# ClassCastException in JUnit tests with Android KitKat

Tags: android, junit

I'm figuring a problem on Android KitKat that didn't appear before.

I'm using JUnit tests with Robotium, and everything in the test works well, except on Android KitKat (tried with a Nexus 4 updated and a nexus 5).

When I want to perform a solo action, I always have the same exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.view.View[]
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getWindowDecorViews(ViewFetcher.java:399)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getAllViews(ViewFetcher.java:81)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Searcher.searchFor(Searcher.java:165)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForView(Waiter.java:254)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForView(Waiter.java:233)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnView(Solo.java:967)
at com.example.TestClass.testMethod(TestClass.java:61)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

May you know if there is a reason for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was with robotium 4.3.

Updating it to the just updated version 4.3.1 solved this issue.